# how to remove non utf 8 code and save as a csv file python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have some amazon review data and I have converted from the text format to CSV format successfully, now the problem is when I trying to read it into a dataframe using pandas, i got error msg: 
*UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 13: invalid start byte*

I understand there must be some non utf-8 in the review raw data, how can I remove the non UTF-8 and save to another CSV file?

thank you!

EDIT1:
Here is the code i convert to text to csv:

```
import csv
import string
INPUT_FILE_NAME = "small-movies.txt"
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "small-movies1.csv"
header = [
    "product/productId",
    "review/userId",
    "review/profileName",
    "review/helpfulness",
    "review/score",
    "review/time",
    "review/summary",
    "review/text"]
f = open(INPUT_FILE_NAME,encoding="utf-8")

outfile = open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,"w")

outfile.write(",".join(header) + "\n")
currentLine = []
for line in f:

   line = line.strip()  
   #need to reomve the , so that the comment review text won't be in many columns
   line = line.replace(',','')

   if line == "":
      outfile.write(",".join(currentLine))
      outfile.write("\n")
      currentLine = []
      continue
   parts = line.split(":",1)
   currentLine.append(parts[1])

if currentLine != []:
    outfile.write(",".join(currentLine))
f.close()
outfile.close()
```

## EDIT2:

Thanks to all of you trying to helping me out. 
So I have solved it by modify the output format in my code:

```
 outfile = open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,"w",encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: More likely that **all** data is not UTF-8 encoded. Show us how you converted the text format to CSV.

Comment: i pasted into my questions. thanks

Comment: Why haven't you specified the encoding of the file you are writing to? It is likely that the default encoding of your OS is something other than utf-8.

Comment: @Dunes you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 8):

If the input file in not utf-8 encoded, it it probably not a good idea to try to read it in utf-8...

You have basically 2 ways to deal with decode errors:

- use a charset that will accept any byte such as iso-8859-15 also known as latin9
- if output should be utf-8 but contains errors, use `errors=ignore` -> silently removes non utf-8 characters, or `errors=replace` -> replaces non utf-8 characters with a replacement marker (usually `?`)

For example:

```
f = open(INPUT_FILE_NAME,encoding="latin9")
```

or

```
f = open(INPUT_FILE_NAME,encoding="utf-8", errors='replace')
```

Comment: This answer is for Python 3.x as OP stated he was using Python 3.4

Comment: i got this by using each of them:

Answer (score -2):

If you are using **python3**, it provides inbuilt support for unicode content -

```
f = open('file.csv', encoding="utf-8")
```

If you still want to remove all unicode data from it, you can read it as a normal text file and remove the unicode content

```
def remove_unicode(string_data):
    """ (str|unicode) -> (str|unicode)

    recovers ascii content from string_data
    """
    if string_data is None:
        return string_data

    if isinstance(string_data, bytes):
        string_data = bytes(string_data.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    else:
        string_data = string_data.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

    remove_ctrl_chars_regex = re.compile(r'[^\x20-\x7e]')

    return remove_ctrl_chars_regex.sub('', string_data)

with open('file.csv', 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
     content = remove_unicode(csv_file.read())
     csv_file.seek(0)
     csv_file.write(content)
```

Now you can read it without any unicode data issues.

Comment: Hi - Thanks a lot for the quick update. i ran the code, but i got this error msg: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
I guess the reason is because when I convert the text file to csv file: f = open(INPUT_FILE_NAME,encoding="utf-8") , the thing is here I have to add encoding utf8 otherwise, my text to csv will throw me this error msg "  return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5206: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: Are you using python 2x or 3x

Comment: it is 3.4 here is my code to convert to text to csv:

Comment: Ok I haven't read your comment clearly, so you are using 'utf-8' encoding to open the file as I mentioned in my edited answer. So, what's the issue now

Comment: I just pasted the convert txt to csv code in my question part.

Comment: It is working when you are adding encoding, Isn't it?

Comment: I have edited my answer to remove unicode content, please give this one a try it should work

Comment: thank you very much. sorry i wasn't being clear at first. I don't know why there is a -1, but i cannot make it to 0 or 1, stackflow say i don't have enough reputation to do so...

Comment: @Jasmine you can only upvote an answer only after you gain 15 reputation, but you can mark it as correct answer if it helped