# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, csv

This is my code.

```
stock_code = open('/home/ubuntu/trading/456.csv', 'r')
csvReader = csv.reader(stock_code)

for st in csvReader:
    eventcode = st[1]
    print(eventcode)
```

I want to know content in excel.
But there are unicodeDecodeError.
How can i fix it?

Comment: please post the full traceback (edit your question, don't post it in the comments) , and which Python version (2.x or 3.x).

Comment: The `csv` you have probably contains some windows characters, windows-1252 encoding, so you could skip those characters, encode with `windows 1252`, or edit the csv file directly to change those chars. This are things like windows fancy inverted commas, the extra long dash, things like that. Questions like this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733615/how-to-remove-non-utf-8-code-and-save-as-a-csv-file-python

Answer (score 0):

The CSV [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) say,

> Since open() is used to open a CSV file for reading, the file will by default be decoded into unicode using the system default encoding...

The error message shows that your system is expecting the file to be using UTF-8 encoding.

**Solutions:**

1. Make sure the file is using the correct encoding.

   For example, open the file using NotePad++, select Encoding from the menu
   and select UTF-8. Then resave the file.
2. Alternatively, specify the encoding of the file when calling open(), like this

```py
my_encoding = 'UTF-8' # or whatever is the encoding of the file.
with open('/home/ubuntu/trading/456.csv', 'r', encoding=my_encoding) as stock_code:
    stock_code = open('/home/ubuntu/trading/456.csv', 'r')
    csvReader = csv.reader(stock_code)

    for st in csvReader:
        eventcode = st[1]
        print(eventcode)
```